# Query for duplicate rows, then run ID of oldest of the duplicate through another query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Alright, so this one is a bit confusing and I'm not quite sure how to acheieve this or if its even possible with TSQL.

I have a piece of software that uses Microsoft SQL Server 2008. There is a table called "iLicuserinfo" that holds a list of logged in users and is used for assigning a concurrent user license to that person. An example of that table is below...

As requested, the sample data as text rather than image...

```
WSID    LoginName   SessionID   Last_Login
WK-221  asmith      370         2015-11-17 13:51:32.543
WK-221  asmith      380         2015-11-17 14:30:05.473
WK-220  jcavan      70          2015-11-17 07:20:21.573
WK-230  ccarmore    450         2015-11-17 08:14:42.747
WK-247  jspoon      160         2015-11-17 11:22:07.060
WK-238  mcalhone    10          2015-11-17 14:24:05.133
WK-250  bcasey      270         2015-11-17 10:48:51.230
WK-203  camel       260         2015-11-17 13:19:36.613
WK-205  kwilson     130         2015-11-17 13:32:52.010
```

What happens is that there are a maximum of 25 concurrent users allowed, and is enforced. The software is glitchy (and the vendor refuses to correct it), and will often crash and not clear the license out of the iLicuserinfo list.

The procedure to correct this is to query that table, find any rows with matching WSID's (which is the host name of the workstation the license is tied to), find which of the two or more duplicate is the oldest, take the SessionID of that row, then run the following query to clear it out....

```
EXEC dbo.CleanAppSessions
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'
EXEC dbo.login_proc
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'
EXEC dbo.sysCleanAppSessions
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'
EXEC dbo.sysReleaseAppSession  @pAppSessionId = NULL
```

Where "NULL" is replaced with the session ID of the discovered duplicate.

What I want to do is create a query that pulls the license table, sorts by WSID, finds duplicates, and of those duplicates grabs the SessionID, then runs the query above with that session ID in place of "NULL".

Using the the screenshot of table data shown in the link above, the row with the SessionID of 370 would be manually cleared out because the last login was an hour before that of SessionID 380.

I have been unsuccessful so far in finding a way to form a query that includes the logic required to compare rows and mark which ones are actual hung up licenses that can be cleared, then run the one or more SessionID's through the above script one at a time.

This looks like a pretty big job to me, but perhaps there's a SQL quru out there that can point me in the right direction of achieving what I want to do?

Comment: Rather than show us a picture of the data, it would be more useful to actually give us the sample in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ROW() function you can get the duplicate records (notice I am grabbing those > 1) then loop through them calling your function. I assume you only need to run the other SPs once so they are outside the loop.

```
DECLARE @Table as table(WSID varchar(50),LoginName varchar(50),SessionID int,Last_Login datetime)
INSERT INTO @Table values ('WK-221','asmith',370,'2015-11-17 13:51:32')
INSERT INTO @Table values ('WK-221','asmith',380,'2015-11-17 14:30:05')
INSERT INTO @Table values ('WK-220','jcavan',70,'2015-11-17 07:20:21')
INSERT INTO @Table values ('WK-230','ccarmore',450,'2015-11-17 08:14:42')

DECLARE @SessionId int

EXEC dbo.CleanAppSessions
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'
EXEC dbo.login_proc
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'
EXEC dbo.sysCleanAppSessions
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'

DECLARE crsr_Tmp CURSOR SCROLL FOR 
    SELECT SessionID FROM (
        SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WSID ORDER BY Last_Login desc) Row FROM @Table
    ) Tmp
    where Row > 1

OPEN crsr_Tmp;
--Start FETCH process      
FETCH NEXT FROM crsr_Tmp
    INTO @SessionId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.sysReleaseAppSession  @pAppSessionId = @SessionId

    --Grab next record from cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM crsr_Tmp
        INTO @SessionId
END
DEALLOCATE crsr_Tmp --clean up cursor
```

Comment: This works like a charm! How could the query be modified to look at rows with duplicate WSID's, then see if there are duplicate LoginName's and remove the oldest of them?

My thinking is that in the case a workstation has another user profile logged in (but locked) that may still be valid. I think the provided query would clean up the oldest license despite the username. Correct?

This would be useful for shared workstations or terminal servers.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. changed `SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WSID ORDER BY Last_Login desc) Row FROM`   to   `SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WSID + LoginName ORDER BY Last_Login desc) Row FROM`. Simply adding "+ Login Name" did the trick, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

To find the dupes and get oldest timestamp, use an aggregate query.

```
SELECT SessionID
FROM Table INNER JOIN (
    SELECT WSID, 
        MIN(timestampField) AS timestampField
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY WSID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t ON Table.WSID = t.WSID AND 
    Table.timestampField = t.timestampField
```

To loop it through the rest of the code, use a [cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).

Comment: The query does pulls SessionID's that I would expect. Very nice! Now, the cursor is a beast I've never dealt with. I guess I have some reading to do.